# Button Navigation with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, material-ui

Header: I am trying to navigate to a new page from my Material UI button using the onClick method. I am confused about what to write in my handleClickSignIn function.

Code snippet from my Header.tsx file:

```
const HatsPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>
      HATS PAGEHH
    </h1>
  </div>
)

function handleClickSignIn() {
  <Route component= {HatsPage}></Route>
}

const Header = () => (
  <div className = 'header'>‚
    <h1 className = 'title'>
      Instaride
    </h1>
    <div className="header-right">
      <Button onClick= {handleClickSignIn}> Sign In</Button>
      <Button> Contact</Button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

This doesn't work and I get errors like:

> expected assignment or function but got expression instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having it that you're generating a `Route` component every time the `Sign In` button is clicked.

Instead, you should use a [`Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component like so:

```
const Header = () => (
  <div className = 'header'>‚
  <h1 className = 'title'>
    Instaride</h1>
  <div className="header-right">
    <Link to={"/login"}> Sign In</Link>
    <Button> Contact</Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will create a link component that, when clicked, will direct to the `/login` URL. To then render components at that URL you'll also need to define a [`Route`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route). You've already done this with but need to define the path like so:

```
<Route path={"/login"} component={HatsPage} />
```

And then note that this `Route`, your `Header` component and any `Link`'s need to be nested within an instance of a [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter).

Comment: 1.Where should I write this <Route> line exactly?
2.So if I am calling my header in my homepage, I need to wrap it with BrowserRouter again? Even if the whole app is wrapped by it in my App.tsx or Index.tsk files?

Comment: You only need one instance of `BrowserRouter`, so no. You do need the `Header` component within the instance of it though. Here's a [pen](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-ganguly-bhb7h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that should help you out!